# Trying to understand how Git works

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I just installed eGit plugin and I'm playing around with it. I'm new to Git.

I've noticed something strange:

I committed sample project "Planets" then I modified one file only Planet.java.

Then I looked in the Git repository folder, and this modified file Planet.java is there, but *none of my other source files are*.

Does this mean if I delete my original project folder from the disk, it will break Git? I mean will I not be able to restore any previous committed version of this project anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "original project folder" *is* your Git repository. Git only exists* within the directory where you performed a `git init`. Its metadata about your files is stored within a hidden `.git` directory *inside* your project directory. If you delete your project directory, you're deleting your local copy of the Git repository.

<sub>*Assuming you haven't explicitly cloned your repository</sub>